# How to create a method to retrieve data using rest API from a database in CakePHP?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am new to CakePHP. I have a website API created with CakePHP. I need to retreive data from the database using a GET or POST request. The table is named testItem. the table has only three field: ID which is the PRIMARY KEY int with AUTOINCREMENT, name which is a varchar, and description (also a varchar).

I have created a model for the table in the Model folder of the website named TestItem which contains this data:

```
<?php

/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: win 7
 * Date: 4/8/2017
 * Time: 3:23 PM
 */
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
App::uses('Security', 'Utility');
App::uses('BlowfishPasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');
App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');

class TestItem extends AppModel {

    // public $hasMany = array(
    //     'Subcategory' => array(
    //         'className' => 'Subcategory',
    //     )
    // );

public $validate = array(
    'name' => array(
         'maxLength' => array(
            'rule' => array('maxLength', 30),
            'message' => 'Category name can not be more than 255 characters.'
          )

     ),
    'description' => array(
         'maxLength' => array(
            'rule' => array('maxLength', 30),
              'message' => 'Category name can not be more than 255 characters.'
          ),

     ),

     );
}
```

What  I want is to retrieve the data from these to field using a rest API.
here is the method I have writted so far in my ApisController.php named api_getTestItem :

```
 public function api_getTestItem() {

        $language = $_REQUEST['lang'];
        $this->TestItem->virtualFields['name'] = "name_$language";
        $cat_list= $this->TestItem->find('all',array('order'=>'TestItem.priority ASC'));

        if(!empty($cat_list)){
            $cat_list = Set::extract('/TestItem/.', $cat_list);
            $this->Basic->response(200,'get_data',$cat_list);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->Basic->response(404,'not_found');
        }
    }
```

But when I execute , I get this error:

> Notice (8): Undefined variable: message [APP\View\Errors\error500.ctp,
>   line 6]

I have already connected the database to my CakePHP website using phpmyadmin.

> I have already searched google and looked into these articles:
>   [Creating a CakePHP REST api from an existing project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264546/creating-a-cakephp-rest-api-from-an-existing-project)
>
> [Cakephp retrieve info from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30014583/cakephp-retrieve-info-from-database)
>
> [Creating REST API with CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27592679/creating-rest-api-with-cakephp)

They were not useful in my situation.
I would truly appreciate any help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well i don't know CakePHP framework but did work with other MVC frameworks in past a educated guess would be to **disable** the automatic view rendering? All those MVC frameworks tends to have some automatic view rendering thats tryes to call a view code (template) if that does not exists you will get a error.

Comment: I was right "Although CakePHP will **automatically call it after every action’s logic** (unless you’ve set $this->autoRender to false), " [source](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html)  you need to use `$this->autoRender = false;` in your controllers functions it seams.

Comment: There are other API's working perfectly within the same viewController (ApisController.php). I tried disabling but still getting the same error. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Where do you think I should put in the code you are suggesting. I tried to insert it into the same api_getTestItem method . but still getting the same error.

Comment: Also `error500.ctp` looks suspect by the way i didn't notice it before.. i geuss the PHP has a error or expection thrown. PHPCake manual explains `error500.ctp.`  in the [Exception](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html) section..

Comment: Thank you @RaymondNijland. I'll look into that.